# Error in importing project from OpenShift to JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: openshift

I have created a Nodejs application (sdgnodeapp) in my OpenShift domain, and was trying to import the sdgnodeapp application using OpenShift Explorer into my empty workspace in JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1 GA .During the Import-Application workspace, I specify the git-clone-directory to be the same as my workspace-directory, JBDS then throws an error

**"Could not import project to the workspace.
Invalid project description.
OK
/Users/sddasgu/SDGDevCode/Node/NodeWorkspace/sdgnodeapp overlaps the location of another project: 'sdgnodeapp'".**

NOTE: If I change the git-clone directory to some other directory (not my workspace-directory), then the project is added to my workspace as expected.
I am used to creating projects inside my workspace-directory, but it seems to me in the above case, that the git-clone happens successfully, but then then the project creation fails. Is there a way to circumvent this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by there already being a directory called 'sdgnodeapp' in your eclipse workspace. Rename the existing one  directory on your machine in your workspace to something different and then run the clone command again. That should fix it

Comment: Thanks TheSteve0 for your response, however before the Import Application was attempted, there was nothing in the /Users/sddasgu/SDGDevCode/Node/NodeWorkspace directory. The first thing that happens during the import is the creation of the git repository directory with the default name (sdgnodeapp), second when the project itself gets created, Eclipse realizes that the directory sdgnodeapp already exists and it aborts. I circumvented the problem by specifying a different git-clone directory than the workspace directory, but my point was that Eclipse should allow for this to happen.

Comment: Agreed - I think you should file a bug